# Passing '*' in variable in bash for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I was wondering how I could pass * in my variable in a bash for loop. I want to run multiple select queries on a db and I thought I'd use a bash for loop like so:

```
for query in "select * from filtertype limit 10;" "select * from filter limit 10;"; do echo $query; echo $query | mysql -uroot -ppassword database; done
```

The trouble is the * keeps on getting expanded like so:

```
[Bash]$ for query in "select * from filtertype limit 10;" "select * from filter limit 10;"; do echo $query; echo $query | mysql -uroot -ppassword database; done
select acceptance_test bin build-dist.xml build-path-definitions.xml build.properties build.xml classes config core-def database dependencies dev.properties dist docs dummyFile_pdffile.pdf eclipse_classes findbugsExcludeFilter.xml generated getRevision.sh local.build.properties log nohup.out plugins-defs plugins-framework pmc-api-client pmd_rules.xml port_helper.sh raw_data-pigunit-input-overridden.txt raw_event_data-pigunit-input-overridden.txt raw-pigunit-input-overridden.txt rpmbuild src testArea unit_test web from filtertype limit 10;
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'build-dist.xml build-path-definitions.xml build.properties build.xml classes con' at line 1
select acceptance_test bin build-dist.xml build-path-definitions.xml build.properties build.xml classes config core-def database dependencies dev.properties dist docs dummyFile_pdffile.pdf eclipse_classes findbugsExcludeFilter.xml generated getRevision.sh local.build.properties log nohup.out plugins-defs plugins-framework pmc-api-client pmd_rules.xml port_helper.sh raw_data-pigunit-input-overridden.txt raw_event_data-pigunit-input-overridden.txt raw-pigunit-input-overridden.txt rpmbuild src testArea unit_test web from filter limit 10;
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'build-dist.xml build-path-definitions.xml build.properties build.xml classes con' at line 1
[Bash]$
```

When I tried single quotes around the loop variables I got the same error and when I single and double quoted the stars I got:

```
select \* from filtertype limit 10;
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\*'.
select \* from filter limit 10;
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\*'.
```

So the question is - is it possible to pass a string variable with a '*' in it into a bash for loop?

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable *references*, `$query`, are *unquoted*, and thus subject to shell expansions (in this case, `*` expands to the names of files and directories in the current directory, a process called pathname expansion).

Thus, simply *double-quote* your variable references to protect them from expansions:

```
echo "$query"
```

Comment: I was typing I found it as you typed. I'll mark yours as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Hope it's at least useful to somebody else. The solution is to quote the variable when it getting called:

```
for query in "select * from filtertype limit 10;" "select * from filter limit 10;"; do echo "$query"; echo "$query" |mysql -uroot -ppassword database; done
```

That works

A